# How to save & retrieve the image's URI though onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-bitmap

I'm trying to work with orientation change.  At the moment, the image in my fragment is gone when I rotate the phone.  This is obviously because the activity is destroyed & recreated.  Instead of trying to save such a large data like an image, I decided to work around that by saving the image's `Uri` in the `onSaveInstanceState` method:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("imageUri", imageUri);
    }
```

And in my fragment's `onCreateView`, I tried to retrieve the Uri and paste it back into the `ImageView` by also keeping the null possibility in mind.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_image, container, false);

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.meme_image_view);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedImage(v);
            }
        });

        topTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.top_text_view);
        bottomTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_text_view);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            if(imageUri != null){
                Uri savedUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageUri");
                imageView.setImageURI(savedUri);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

And for some reason, it doesn't work.  The image is still lost when I rotate the phone.

Full fragment:

```
public class TopImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView topTextView, bottomTextView;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    Uri imageUri;
    int counter = 0;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());

    MemeViewModel memeViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_image, container, false);

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.meme_image_view);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedImage(v);
            }
        });

        topTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.top_text_view);
        bottomTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_text_view);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            Uri savedUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageUri");
            imageView.setImageURI(savedUri);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("imageUri", imageUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        memeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(MemeViewModel.class);

        memeViewModel.getTopText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                topTextView.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });

        memeViewModel.getBottomText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                bottomTextView.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectedImage(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    public void createBitmapAndSave(ImageView img) {

        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        String topText = topTextView.getText().toString();
        String bottomText = bottomTextView.getText().toString();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        TextPaint topPaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomPaint = new TextPaint();
        Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.impact);

        topPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        topPaint.setShadowLayer(10f, 10f, 10f, Color.BLACK);
        topPaint.setTextSize(topTextView.getTextSize());
        topPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        bottomPaint.setShadowLayer(10f, 10f, 10f, Color.BLACK);
        bottomPaint.setTextSize(bottomTextView.getTextSize());
        bottomPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        float topTextMeasurement = topPaint.measureText(topText);
        float bottomTextMeasurement = bottomPaint.measureText(bottomText);

        StaticLayout topLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f,
                0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, false);

        canvas.translate(0,0);
        topLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight() - 210);
        bottomLayout.draw(canvas);
        counter++;

        File file;
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
        file = new File(path + "/SimpliMeme/" + timeStamp + "-" + counter + ".jpg");
        file.getParentFile().mkdir();

        try {
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Top Text: " + String.valueOf(topTextMeasurement) + " and bottom text: " + String.valueOf(bottomTextMeasurement),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            memeViewModel.setSharedId(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(listener, new IntentFilter("CUSTOM_ACTION"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver listener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
            createBitmapAndSave(imageView);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(listener);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

These are the changes I've made to my `onCreateView` method.  Turns out, I was not saving the retrieved `Uri` to the `imageUri` field

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            imageUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageUri");
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
outState.putString(String.valueOf(imageUri), "imageUri");
```

with:

```
outState.putParcelable("imageUri", imageUri);
```

and replace:

```
String raw = savedInstanceState.getString("imageUri");
Uri savedUri = Uri.parse(raw);
```

with:

```
Uri savedUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imageUri");
```

The `put...()` methods on `Bundle` take the key, followed by the value. You have the value, followed by the key. And, in the case of `Uri`, you do not need to convert it to and from `String`.

Comment: Doesn't work.  I've added your changes but the image is not saved on rotation change.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Check to confirm whether you are getting the `Uri` or not from the `Bundle`. And you probably need to get rid of the `if(imageUri != null)` check, since you are doing that before you set the value of `imageUri` in the new activity instance.

Comment: I have a global `Uri imageUri`, which isn't initialized.  It gets initialized when the user calls a different method that handles the selection and editing of the image.  I'll post my full class to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: So there is a change that it is taking an empty Uri when the fragment is created.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: "I have a global Uri imageUri" -- no, you do not. You have a field in your `TopImageFragment` Java class. When the screen rotates, you get a completely new instance of `TopImageFragment`. In that instance, `imageUri` is `null`, which is why you need to look in the `Bundle` for it. However, you are not looking in the `Bundle` for it, because you have the `if(imageUri != null)` check. Remove the `if(imageUri != null)`, or at least move it to after where you set `imageUri`.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: OK. Then put breakpoints or logging statements in your code and confirm that you are getting the `Uri` out of the `Bundle`. Either you are, you try but the `Bundle` returns `null`, or that block of code is not getting executed. That latter scenario does not look possible given your code, so we need to determine which of the former two scenarios is happening.

Comment: I've placed this log `Log.d(String.valueOf(savedUri), "This is the URI that is returned from the Bundle");` and this is what I got from the logcat:

`2019-03-09 16:12:46.070 25184-25184/com.example.omar.memegenerator D/content://media/external/images/media/104185: This is the URI that is returned from the Bundle`

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: OK, perhaps you are losing access rights to the content identified by that `Uri`. I did not think that happened on a configuration change, though.

Comment: how can I come across that?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Do you have "Don't keep activities" checked in Developer Options in Settings? If so, uncheck it, and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: No, its not checked.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Then I cannot explain the behavior. However, your problem is not saving and retrieving the `Uri` anymore -- it's that the `Uri` does not seem usable after the configuration change. So, you might want to ask a different Stack Overflow question, showing your updated code and targeting that problem. Check Logcat for messages at the point when you rotate the screen, and include that Logcat output in the new question.

Comment: Thank you, @CommonsWare.  I'll accept and upvote your answer anyways, as it still solves earlier problems that I had with my code.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: Just a quick heads up.  The Image does show in the first rotation.  In the 2nd rotation, however, the image disappears.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Oh! That changes things. Note that in your current code, you are getting the `Uri` and putting it in a local variable (`savedUri`). That is not your `imageUri` field, which will remain `null`. So, on the second rotation, `onSaveInstanceState()` saves `null` to the `Bundle`. You should see that your third fragment instance is getting `null` from the `Bundle`.

Comment: So I should saved the retrieved `Uri` in my `imageUri` field?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Presumably yes. One way or another, you need `onSaveInstanceState()` to have access to the `Uri`.

Comment: Everything is working now.  Check my update.  Thank you, @CommonsWare

Comment: Hello.  If you can, could you take a look at this question?  I've been struggling with it for a few days.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295574/how-to-adjust-the-canvas-and-the-imageview-based-on-the-image-size

Comment: The image uri points the image path in the cache directory yet the image is saved in another directory.